# Failed to Upload an app on Google Play, certificate not valid

Tags: java, android, google-play

Please help me, I stuck on this issue.

I created some apps using my computer and there was no problem. However when I create an app on another computer, I get this problem. I do not have any problems creating apps, I get into trouble when I want to upload an app in the google play store.

> **Upload failed**
>
> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate
>   that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle
>   with a certificate that is currently valid. Learn more about signing.

**UPDATE!**
I have tried to create an app using a certificate I created from another computer and IT WORKS!
Now I know my problem is on the certificate created on this computer.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: The error message exactly tells you what the problem is: You are using a non-signed certificate. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) how to sign your app.

Comment: @Ben, no, I have followed everything. As I said, I got this problem when I used another computer.

Comment: `a certificate that is not yet valid` - probably time settings on the PC you have signed your APK on is incorrect.

Comment: Did you sign your app with the same certificate on the other computer?

Comment: @PeterBruins, WOW GOD LIKE! I try to build an app using same  certificate from my another computer and IT WORKS! Now I know my problem is when creating keystore on this computer.. Please tell me how to fix it :D

Comment: You have to change the timezone or waiting a couple of ours

Comment: Use the same .jks file it will solve your problem!

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan I am creating new app with new certificate. I have created new certificate from another machine and I used that certificate to build an app on this computer and it works.. I think the problem is in creating certificate from this computer.

Answer (score 1):

An App should have only 1 certificate. When an app is built on a different machine, it still should be signed with the same certificate. When uploading your app, this signing provides proof to Google it is an update of the **same** app.

Otherwise someone else could upload an completely different app, pretending to be an update of your app, when he got your login credentials, or you left your browser open.

Comment: It is new app (new packagename) with new sertificate. I created new certificate from another computer and build new app in this computer and it works.. so, I think the problem is in creating certificate from this computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Install proxy VPN client in your PC and change your location to the location that you mentioned in your google play console (like USA)
2. Change the time also in  your PC with the same time zone for the location you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a code specific problem, try uploading it in google chrome incognito mode.

Comment: The problem is not in the browser. I've tried uploading an application created by another computer and it's no problem

Answer (score 0):

Print the keystore and see what is different when produced from the two computers. My bet would be your timesettings are wrong on your computer, but without displaying the info it is hard to tell. To print information about a keystore do:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore .keystore
```