# Upload failed to google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signed-apk

I face this problem when I want to upload an app in the google play store :-

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a certificate that is currently valid. Find out more about signing.

pleas help
Not: i solve that by change the date of pc

Comment: check both V1 and V2 signatures when creating the APK

Comment: how could i check it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggIyj.png

Comment: ok i have check the both when i created the  apk? is that wrong

Comment: you need to check both , else there will be error

Comment: that  what i did but that error still appear when i try upload the apk in google play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the certificate your app is signed with, you have to specify a **start date** and an **expiry date**.

It looks like the **start date** set on your certificate is in the future, so technically, your certificate is not valid. That's what this error message indicates.

How did you create the keystore? Consider creating a new one. See instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your APK with a valid key before uploading to the store. You also have to pay a  $25 fee once to get registered as a Play Store developer. See more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).

Comment: i pay the fee and now i have developer account ,my problem is when i upload the apk to the message i have mention above ,also i read every thing about signing and do the same steps ,please help

Comment: Please take a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693935/failed-to-upload-an-app-on-google-play-certificate-not-valid

Comment: i see this answer before its not work for me , any other help please?